# Multidimensional Vector?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

So I recently started learning C++ and I'm trying to figure out how to access a multidimensional vector or a vector with vectors stored inside of it. I've looked all over and I can't find exactly what I'm looking for. I want to be able to test the contents of each vector inside of the multidimensional vector by printing them out. Also whenever I try to see the size of the vector after each iteration, I'm getting random constants for each iteration. They look like they may be memory locations but I'm not sure.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
int numofArrays;
int numofQueries;

vector<vector<int>> arr(numofArrays);

cin >> numofArrays;
cin >> numofQueries;

int arrSize;
int number;
vector<int> indArr; 

// Outer loop, appends vectors containing ints to a multidimensional vector
for (int i = 0; i < numofArrays; i++) {
    cin >> arrSize; // Getting number of elements from user

    // Inner loop, gets user inputted values then creates a vector which is added to the multidimensional vector
    for (int x = 0; x < arrSize; x++) {
        cin >> number; 
        indArr.push_back(number); 
        cout << "Last number added to vector: " << number << endl; // Checking to see if correct numbers are being added. 
    }

    arr.push_back(indArr);
    cout << "Multidimensional Vector size: " << arr.size() << endl; // Checking size of vector after each iteration
    indArr.clear(); // Empties vector for next iteration
}


  return 0;
}
```

> As I am very new to C++, I welcome constructive criticism.

Newly Revised Code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
int numofArrays;
int numofQueries;


cin >> numofArrays;
cin >> numofQueries;

vector<vector<int>> arr(numofArrays);


// Outer loop, appends vectors containing ints to a multidimensional vector
for (int i = 0; i < numofArrays; i++) {
    int arrSize;
    vector<int>indArr;
    cin >> arrSize; // Getting number of elements from user
    indArr.resize(arrSize); // Resizing array for next values
    // Inner loop, gets user inputted values then creates a vector which is added to the multidimensional vector
    for (int x = 0; x < arrSize; x++) {
        int number;
        cin >> number; 
        indArr.push_back(number); 
        cout << "Last number added to vector: " << number << endl; // Checking to see if correct numbers are being added. 
    }

    arr.push_back(indArr);
    cout << "Multidimensional Vector size: " << arr.size() << endl; // Checking size of vector after each iteration
}

int test = arr[0][0];
cout << test;



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: All you need to do is figure out how to use a vector, because a "multi-dimensional vector" is just a vector.

Comment: But I've used vectors before and it's not behaving like any vector. Can you explain what I'm doing wrong? Why is it that whenever I print out the line     "cout << "Multidimensional Vector size: " << arr.size() << endl; // Checking size of vector after each iteration", I'm receiving a number over 4000000?

Comment: Probably something boring like a bug in your code.

Comment: For matrices I recommend using a linear algebra library like [Blaze](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze) or [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Comment: Thanks for some actual suggestions Henri, I would do that but it's just a simple challenge on Hackerrank. Everything else was easy but for some reason, I can't print the values inside of vectors in the multidimensional vector and whenever I print out the size, it shows an exceptionally large number.

Comment: You apparently forgot to initalize numofArrays before passing it into the constructor of vector

Comment: Thanks I fixed it but the problem is still persisting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some tips:

`vector<vector<int>> arr(numofArrays);` constructs a vector of vectors of size `numofArrays`. But numofArrays is not yet read from cin, so it is an undefined number. Care with the order of operations.

`arr.push_back(indArr);` adds a vector at the end of arr.

Hence, in your loop, even if you fix the order of reading `numofArrays` and declaring `arr`, you start with an array of size `numofArrays`, and each cycle you add an element. You will end up with arr holding 2 times `numofArrays` elements.

Also, `indArr` is a temporary variable, which you reset each cycle. Although there is nothing wrong about what you are doing, in general is better to keep each variable limited to its scope. If you define `indArr` inside the loop, it will be automatically cleared and re-created. May not be the most efficient way to do things in all cases, but I'd leave this details for later.

Something like this should work for you:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int numofArrays;
  int numofQueries;

  cin >> numofArrays; 
  cin >> numofQueries; // this is an unused variable

  vector<vector<int> > arr;

  // Outer loop, set vectors containing ints to a multidimensional vector
  for (int i = 0; i < numofArrays; i++) {
    int arrSize;
    vector<int> indArr; 
    cin >> arrSize; // Getting number of elements from user

    // Inner loop, gets user inputted values then creates a vector which is added to the multidimensional vector
    for (int x = 0; x < arrSize; x++) {
      int number;
      cin >> number; 
      indArr.push_back(number); 
        cout << "Last number added to vector: " << number << endl; // Checking to see if correct numbers are being added. 
    }

    arr.push_back(indArr);
    cout << "Multidimensional Vector size: " << arr.size() << endl; // Checking size of vector after each iteration
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I used your advice and I'm receiving a segmentation fault whenever I try to print out one of the values from a vector

Comment: I don't get segfaults. Can you post the offending code?

Comment: Also numofQueries will be used but the program isn't over yet.

Comment: Please re-read my answer and my code. In your revised code, you still initialize `arr` as a non-empty with `vector<vector<int>> arr(numofArrays)`. Hence `arr[0]` points at something, but it is an empty array. That's why you get the error when trying to access `arr[0][0]`, because there is no first element. `

Comment: Thanks your solution solved my issue, now I can finish the rest of the program. I really appreciate it man. I'm still getting used to how C++ works, it seems incredibly expansive but really awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're inspecting the size is correct. For example in your code you're printing the integer number of elements in the first dimension of the array `arr`.

The odd results you're getting is because of how you're initializing the vector. In the constructor for `arr` there you specify a size describing the number of default-constructed elements to fill the vector with. However you're providing `numofArrays` which is an undefined value. Hence you receive random looking vector sizes when you print this out.

The real size of the vector `arr`'s first dimension will be whatever this undefined value is plus one, due to the `push_back` operation.